# Failed to start STS 3.6.1. release

Tags: spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When I start STS I get the following error message:

```
An internal error occurred During: Initializing Java Tooling  
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Then I can not find the tools to work with ROO.

First, please provide me with guidance on how to resolve this error, and I want to ask whether the lack of tools to ROO is related to the startup error.

Thank you already very much for your attention.

Gustavo Echenique

Answer (score 0):

Roo doesn't have support for Java 8 yet, check it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply eruiz!

I have installed the JDK 7, but as I have understood, is version 1.7.0.

Can it be that the problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Roo works fine with JDK 1.7. On the other side, since STS 3.5.0 Roo isn't installed by default, so check you have Roo installed or install it as STS plugin.